# How to hide the "If you have a coupon code, enter it here" option, in an online registration form to an event?

Tags: cividiscount

How to hide the "If you have a coupon code, enter it here" option, in an online registration form to an event?

Comment: I have the same question. I'm using an automatic 100% off for contacts who are part of smart group that codes for membership status. I don't want the "enter the code" option on the form either. No idea how to get rid of it though.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no code that applies to either the event or a price line item that is used in the event price set the discount code block should not appear.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it with CSS though you may need some JS if you want the "enter discount code" to appear on some event/contribution pages but not on others (so you need to examine the URL).